# Jira Python Custom Field

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api

I have a custom field that I must update and I keep getting this message:

```
response text = {"errorMessages":["Internal server error"],"errors":{}}
```

after this line:

```
issue.update({"customfield_10201": '0.0'})
```

Though if I put anything else than a simple string like:

```
 issue.update({"customfield_10201": 0.0})
```

I get this message:

```
response text = {"errorMessages":["Internal server error"],"errors":{"customfield_10201":"data was not a string"}}
```

This is the type of field according to jira API:

```
{"required":false,"schema":{"type":"any","custom":"SMTH.jira.plugins.componentversionmanager:elementversioncft","customId":10201}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, welcome at stackoverflow.com;-)

Based on [Jira Python client documentation](https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#issues), you need to update issue fields this way:

```
issue.update(customfield_10201='0.0')
```

If you further have troubles, do specify the following:

- What Jira API client in Python do you use?
- What is the exact type of custom field? It looks like the custom field comes from an add-on/app. What addon is it?
- Are you connecting to Server or Cloud Jira?
- Are you able to update the field directly using native Jira API? E.g. using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), [Jira REST API Browser](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211542/atlassian-rest-api-browser?hosting=server&tab=overview) or other similar easy to use API client? You might want to check [official Jira API documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/8.6.0/#api/2/issue-editIssue) on how to update Jira issues.